# What is a cleaner/ OOP way to write this?

Tags: jquery, oop

Short and to the point. What is a better way to write this so I'm not repeating the same code over and over.

```
$('.login').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.model._login').fadeIn();
    $('body').addClass('no-scroll')
});

$('._view-observations').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.model._key-observations-model').fadeIn();
    $('body').addClass('no-scroll')
});

$('._forgottenPW').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.model._forgottenPW').fadeIn();
    $('body').addClass('no-scroll')
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: wright should be written as write

Comment: Put a `data` attribute on your items that associates the button to the element that should fade in. Apply a common class to all three buttons. Have one button handler for that class, and fadeIn the element using the clicked button's `data` attribute.

Comment: Thank you Kevin! Wasn't paying attention!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put the name of the class you're trying to fade-in as a `data-element` attribute on the buttons themselves. Then, add a common class `btn-fadein` to all of them.

This allows you to re-use a single handler, referencing the `data-element` attribute to show the corresponding element.

```js
$(".btn-fadein").click(function(e) {
  var elemClass = $(this).data("element"); //Get data-element value
  var $elem = $(".model." + elemClass);    //Use it to select the correct element
  $elem.fadeIn();                          //Fade in the element    
        
  e.preventDefault();
  $('body').addClass('no-scroll');
});
```

```css
.model {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="login btn-fadein" data-element="_login">Login</button>
<button class="_view-observations btn-fadein" data-element="_key-observations-model">View Observations</button>
<button class="_forgottenPW btn-fadein" data-element="_forgottenPW">Login</button>

<div class="model _login">login</div>
<div class="model _key-observations-model">key observations model</div>
<div class="model _forgottenPW">forgotten pw</div>
```

Comment: This is awesome! Works great and I really appreciate the tip for using the data-attributes. Makes for a lot cleaner HTML as well as the jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way using a multidimensional array.

```js
var elements = [
  ['.login', '.model._login'],
  ['._view-observations', '.model._key-observations-model'],
  ['._forgottenPW', '.model._forgottenPW']
];

$.each(elements, function(i, j) {
  $(j[0]).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(j[1]).fadeIn();
    $('body').addClass('no-scroll')
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! This did work but there was a better method above.

Comment: @Satrop Indeed, Santi's method is definitely cleaner!

Answer (score 1):

Identify the redundant code and abstract it out.

The only difference between each of these is the name of the class that gets faded in, so this function takes a class name as an argument and returns a new function:

```
const generateClickHandler = classToFadeIn => e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(classToFadeIn).fadeIn();
    $('body').addClass('no-scroll')
}

$('.login').click(generateClickHandler('.model._login'));
$('._view-observations').click(generateClickHandler('.model._key-observations-model'));
$('._forgottenPW').click(generateClickHandler('.model._forgottenPW'));
```

Comment: Might be worth noting (as much as we all wish it was dead-and-gone) that if for whatever reason you need to support IE, arrow functions will not work.

Comment: True -- and the aesthetics of curried functions *plummet* without arrow syntax, lol.